# regex for position matching with OR condition

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

Newbie to regex and looking for help in creating regexp to seek out following:

The data items consists of six character strings as shown in example below

1)  "100100"

2)  "110011"

3)  "010000"

4)  "110011"

5)  "111111"

6)  "000111"

Need to use regexp to find data with say

- 1 in the 1st position OR 1 in the 4th position:  Items 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6 should be matched
- 1 in 2nd position: Items 2,4 ad 5 should be matched
- 1 in 5th and 6th position: Items 2, 4, 5 and 6 should be matched

Comment: can you be a little more clear on the matching conditions, the way you have written them, I am not sure which condition are OR or AND and how they might be nested.  Perhaps write each matching condition on a separate line.

Comment: I cannot see why 2 and 4 does not match with case 1 - they have 1 in the first position - do you really just mean the 4th position?

Comment: Mike - all conditions are OR conditions; There was an error in my question as pointed out by Morten which is what confused you. Thanks.

Comment: Morten - thanks for pointing out the error..I've made the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your samples, these will work:

- 1 in the 1st position OR 1 in the 4th position: Items 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6 should be matched

`1.....|...1...`

- 1 in 2nd position: Items 2,4 ad 5 should be matched

`.1....`

- 1 in 5th and 6th position: Items 2, 4, 5 and 6 should be matched

`....11`

Or if you want to match *any* of these rules, combine them with the `|` (or) operator.

Example:

http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(1.....%7C...1...%7C.1....%7C....11)&input=100100%0A%0A110011%0A%0A010000%0A%0A110011%0A%0A111111%0A%0A000111

Comment: Great, this works...learnt a little bit more about regex today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always strings with only 1s and 0s, you should treat them as binary numbers and use logical operators to find the matches.

Comment: Do not have a choice because using a third-party software component that accepts regex for filtering data

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
([1][0-1]{2}[1][0-1]{2})|([0-1][1][0-1]{4})|([0-1]{4}[1]{2})
```

Find the explanation and demo here http://www.regex101.com/r/vD9jE7

Comment: Used @doctororange 's solution although this works too. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. Change dots with zeros if necessary.  `/^(11..|.1.1)11$/`

```
^              # beginning of string
(              # either
    11..     # 11 and any 2 char
    |          # or
    .1.1     # any char, 1, any char, 1
)
11
$             # end of string
```